# How to style third party web part in SharePoint 2013 Online?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, iframe, style

I have a web part added into the page and would like to style its look and feel. The issue is that the web part is appearing under an iframe and I cannot seem to apply style to its DOM under the iframe.

How can I override the css classes that apply to the html under the web part.

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe contains content from a different domain, there's nothing you can do. 
Otherwise, if you are on the same domain, Javascript from the parent page can interact with the contents of the frame (change the CSS). The parent's page CSS won't affect the iframe. For more info refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe